# custom validation acces form components

Tags: angular, custom-validators

I want to make a custom validation for angular2. This validation must access another component of the form. Is this possible?

**My template**

```
<input type="tekst" id="startDate" name="startDate" [(ngModel)]="model.startDate" #startDate="ngModel" >

<input type="tekst" id="endDate" name="endDate" [(ngModel)]="model.endDate" #endDate="ngModel" customValidator>
```

**My validator**

```
...
@Directive({
    selector: '[customValidator][ngModel][customValidator][formControl]',
    providers: [
        provide : NG_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting : forwardRef(() = > CustomValidator),
        Multi : true
    }]
})

export class CustomValidator impelments Validator {
    constructor(){}

    validate(c : FormControl) : {[key : string] : any} {

        // HOW TO ACCESS startDate CONTROL HERE? OR ITS VALUE? OR THE MODEL
    }
```

Comment: Yes its possible,can you update your module file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement cross validation you should move the validation to the ancestor control.

Then your validate method can look like this:

```
validate(fg: FormGroup) {
  const start = fg.get('startDate').value;
  const end = fg.get('enDate').value;

  return start !== null && end !== null && start < end 
   ? null 
   : { range: true };
};
```

Read more about cross validation [here](https://medium.com/@realTomaszKula/angular-cross-field-validation-d94e0d063b61).

Comment: do you have an example how to do this with form template. So to put a validator in the html control < input .. customValidator > and without the formbuilder in typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You can like

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[customValidator][ngModel][customValidator][formControl]',
    providers: [
        provide : NG_VALIDATORS,
        useExisting : forwardRef(() = > CustomValidator),
        Multi : true
    }]
})

export class CustomValidator impelments Validator {
    constructor(){}

    validate(c : FormControl) : {[key : string] : any} {
         let control_value= c.value;
        // HOW TO ACCESS startDate CONTROL HERE? OR ITS VALUE? OR THE MODEL
    }
```

also refer this link also: [custom validator](https://codeburst.io/angular-4-custom-validation-for-template-based-forms-b7dee9be48a6) and [custom validtor with reverse match](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-custom-validator-directive-confirm-password-in-angular-2)

Comment: i want to acces another control here. If I do c.root.get('control') its also null

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-implement-a-custom-validator-directive-confirm-password-in-angular-2

Comment: check the above links

Comment: hi Robert, thnx for youre reply, only if I do the code       let e = c.root.get(this.validateEqual);  this results in null